# Can't use select on javascript loaded JQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

What I am trying to do is simple. I want to load jQuery UI Tabs only when a button is clicked. And then I want them to show a specific Tab. The first part works the second won't. Any ideas on what am I doing  wrong!!!

```
$('[name="testBtn"]')
.click(function(){
  $("#main").load("test.html", function() {
    $(col3).empty();
    var tabs = $("#tabs");
    $(tabs).tabs();
    $(tabs).tabs('select', 3);
  });
```

I Have used this way also:

```
$('[name="testBtn"]')
.click(function(){
  $("#main").load("test.html", function() {
    $(col3).empty();
    $("#tabs").tabs('select', 3);
  });
```

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Test 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the real HTML have at least 4 tabs? Don't forget that tab indexes are zero-based.

Comment: BTW, the "select" method was renamed to "activate" in jQuery UI 1.9, although the old name is retained for compatibility.

Comment: Yes the real html has 5 tabs. I had to cut it down for space.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to find how to implement it. Many thanks to Barmar for pointing out the new activate method. I should have read the manual :) The code for the button is as follows:

```
$('[name="testBtn"]')
.click(function(){
  $("#main").load("test.html", function() {
    $(col3).empty();
    var tabs = $("#tabs");
    $(tabs).tabs();
    $(tabs).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
  });
```

Everything is explained on the api page: [jQuery UI Tabs api page](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)